# rails renders fast but view slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Using rails 4.1 & 4.1.0rc2

We're having this weird issue with rendering:

```
I, [2014-04-13T07:45:28.856574 #5695]  INFO -- : Started GET "/xpto" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2014-04-13 07:45:28 +0000
I, [2014-04-13T07:45:28.916947 #5695]  INFO -- : Processing by XptoController#index as HTML
D, [2014-04-13T07:45:28.952666 #5695] DEBUG -- :   Cart Load (2.5ms)  sql
D, [2014-04-13T07:45:29.000582 #5695] DEBUG -- :   SQL (2.5ms)  sql
D, [2014-04-13T07:45:29.004601 #5695] DEBUG -- :   SQL (2.6ms)  sql
I, [2014-04-13T07:45:29.026042 #5695]  INFO -- :   Rendered xpto/index.html.erb within layouts/application (58.4ms)
I, [2014-04-13T07:45:29.719445 #5695]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 802ms (Views: 735.2ms | ActiveRecord: 31.4ms)
```

As you can see in the log the render took `58.4ms` but the "View" took `735.2ms`. Every data is being preloaded and the view consists only of:

```
<h1>xptos</h1>
<% @xptos.each do |xpto| %>
   <p>link: <%= link_to xpto.name, xptos_path(xpto) %> (ID: <%= xpto.id %>)</p>
<% end %>
```

The configurations used:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.force_ssl = false
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :fog,
    fog_credentials:  { provider: 'aws',
                        aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                        aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
                      },
    fog_directory: 'xpto-bucket'
  }
end
```

Requests are being served directly by Unicorn with config:

```
log_path = 'log/unicorn.log'
pid_path = 'tmp/pids/unicorn.pid'

pid pid_path
worker_processes 8
timeout 15
preload_app true
listen 3000, backlog: 1025

stderr_path log_path
stdout_path log_path

before_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end
```

Is there any way to debug what is taking so long after render but before returning the response?

Comment: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler You could try that out, maybe you can narrow down which view is taking so long to render!